# Standard Error differences Binomial Regression vs Poisson Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, logit

I'm running three different models on a dataset found in table 9.1 of Dobson's Introduction to Generalized Linear Models textbook.

Model 1 is a poisson regression, Model 2 is a binomial regression and model 3 is a bernoulli regression.

All three models are expected to provide roughly equivalent estimates and standard errors.

Using the Python statsmodel library I fit the three models and find roughly equivalent point estimates for the parameters, but differing standard errors - models 1 and 3 have the same, low standard errors, while model 2 does not.

Anyone have any idea as to why this is? The main code used is pasted below

Model 1

```
y,X = pts.dmatrices("Deaths ~ Smoker + AgeCat + agesq + smkage" ,data=data,return_type='dataframe')
model = Poisson(y,X,offset=np.log(data.Person_Years).values)
fit = model.fit()
```

Model 2:

```
y,X = pts.dmatrices("RATE ~ Smoker + AgeCat + agesq + smkage",         data=data,return_type='dataframe')
model = sm.GLM(y,X, family=sm.families.Binomial())
fit = model.fit()
fit.summary()
```

Comment: My guess, based on your `"RATE"` in the binomial formula is that you are not using it as binomial model. binomial should have counts (success, failure) as dependent variable endog y. Otherwise, you need to use a robust covariance matrix and exposure. Long answer: there are many versions for variance calculations in GLM with overdispersion, scaling, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poisson, Binomial and Bernoulli are all count models, where the dependent variables are counts. The exposure or sample size for an individual count is given by exposure in Poisson, total number of trials in Binomial, and equal to 1 in Bernoulli.
Binomial is the only one that takes a dependent variable that has two columns, where columns are the counts for successes and failures.

They give roughly the same results for small probabilities of a count per unit of exposure, i.e. small rates. Otherwise, Poisson is based on an exponential mean function and Binomial and Bernoulli are based on logistic mean function by default which will result in different parameters.
The Poisson variance function also differs from the variance function of Binomial and Bernoulli.

All three families can also be applied to rates and proportions. But the variance function needs to be adjusted to take account of the scaling. 
One possibility is to assume that individual observations are means of a group of observations and we can use variance or dispersion weights to adjust for different group sizes. If all group sizes are the same, then the adjustment is only needed for the over or under dispersion factor.

In general, we can estimate the mean parameters consistently even if the variance is misspecified because all three distributions belong to the linear exponential family. We can correct the standard errors for the parameter estimates by using a (Godambe-Eicker-Huber-)White sandwich covariance estimate which corrects for dispersion and heteroscedasticity.

Specific to statsmodels:

- variance weights are not implemented yet (but will be soon)
- pure overdispersion is implemented (but not advertised, and maybe insufficiently verified)
- standard robust sandwich covariances are available with the `cov_type` option in fit, which allows for heteroscedasticity robust (HC), cluster robust, and heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation robust (HAC) and two panel robust covariance estimators.

The statsmodels documentation for robust covariance matrices is not very good, instead here are two more descriptive blog notebooks:

Quantopian lecture series (uses old version for specifying cov_type)
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/quantopian/research_public/blob/master/lectures/Violation%20of%20Regression%20Model%20Assumptions.ipynb#Correcting-for-Heteroskedasticity

The following illustrates recommended usage with `cov_type` in `fit`
http://www.vincentgregoire.com/standard-errors-in-python/#OLS-Coefficients-and-White-Standard-Errors

Comment: I suspect it is the variance weights - do you have any idea if there is some options I can use within the existing package without writing something manually?

Comment: var_weights are not yet available. Using counts in Binomial does the right thing, otherwise use `cov_type="HC0"`. Current work in progress is at https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/2879 . Frequency weights were just added to statsmodels master and could be "misused" in some cases where different kinds of weights are equivalent.

Comment: understood-kind of . Mind sending me a reference where I can find out more about what this cov_type setting does. I'm looking through the docs and source code right now, but if you know where to look that'll speed my search. (Thanks for all your help)

Comment: I added two links to blogs and notebooks that use the robust covariance matrices. `cov_type` works the same way also for GLM. (statsmodels documentation for this is "not very good", and my examples for Poisson and GLM are "somewhere".)

Comment: @Adam Here is a notebook that I started a while ago to compare robust standard errors for different models for count data including Poisson, GLM and GEE http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/josef-pkt/misc/blob/compare_discrete_glm_cluster/notebooks/compare_discrete_glm_gee_cluster_robust.ipynb